# Run Unity game on Tizen Emulator

Tags: unity-game-engine, emulation, tizen

I am developing a game for Tizen OS using Unity3D. I have setup tizen sdk and tizen emulator. The problem is when I run (Build Settings -> Build and Run) the game installs on the emulator but doesnt run. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged [android]?

Comment: you need to post log. tizen must have something like logcat. there is no meaning to life without logs.

Comment: If you happens to be an Indonesian, or want an active Tizen group which you can discuss in english, you can join https://www.facebook.com/groups/777410855692863/

Comment: Logcat is not showing any error.

Comment: According to Unity Official Documentation Emulator is not supported Unity Tizen Game. You need to deploy your game in A Tizen Device.

Reference:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/tizen-faq.html

Comment: "I am developing a game for Tizen" ... wow!  you rock

Comment: @MehediAlamgir well thats sad. Thanks mehedi.

Comment: @JoeBlow amm.... Didn't get you...?

Comment: @Khubaib You can accept this as answer so that it can be helpful to others having the same problem.

Comment: just saying it is cool !  not many people do it.

Comment: @JoeBlow thanks joe. Actually i was trying to port one of my android game to tizen. But... No support for the tizen emulator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Unity Official Documentation, Unity Tizen Game is not supported in Emulator . You need to deploy your game in A Tizen Device.

Reference: From Unity Documentatuon
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/tizen-faq.html

Comment: Hi I dont have a Tizen device yet is there any other way to get the build running in the Emulator, some hack or something.

Comment: You can test your application in Z series device using Samsung Remote Test Lab from the following site.

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action?os=103

Check RTL manual from the following link

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlHelpDevice.action

Comment: Is only ARM supported ?